# AHK for coding snippets with hotstrings

Tags: autohotkey

So I want to use AHK to create universal snippets because I code in a few different programs, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to include a variable spot or jump to a variable. This is what I have now:

```
::shh::var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`nvar ss = sh.getSheetByName("name");`nvar data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
```

creates

```
sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getSheetByName("name");
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
```

But what if I want a good way to jump the cursor to the "**name**" part of the pasted string? this seems like something someone else will have solved but I don't want an entire snippets program, just the easiest way to imitate the {variable} or ^variable features of robust editors.

Is the solution to then press back arrow x number of times? Seems clunky.

To start a loop where you paste part one of the snippet, wait for a space, and then paste part two?

Some other input idea I'm not thinking of? I'd rather not use ui stuff but that might be the path forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my hope of easily avoiding a ui input seem to have been misplaced, but I'll get over it.

For the most part I used inputboxes like this:

```
:*:arr]:: ; snippet for setting an array to the sheet
{
    InputBox, arrayName,Array GAS Snippet, Array name?,,,,0,300
    clipboard = 
        (
        ss.getRange(row+3, 1,%arrayName%.length, %arrayName%[0].length).setValues(%arrayName%);
        )
    send ^v
    return
}
```

I also have just one that works the way I originally intended, sending the first part of the script, waiting for me to type and then press "control" and then sending the rest, but the use of variables just feels more powerful.

This is how that one looks, if anyone is curious:

```
:*:sh]:: ; snippet that sends the spreadsheet app thingies
{
clipboard = 
(
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`r`nvar ss = sh.getSheetByName("
)
send ^v
sleep, 2000

KeyWait Control, D
clipboard = 
(
");`r`nvar data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
)
send ^v
return
}
```

Comment: If you use the [Input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) command instead of InputBox you avoid the input window. Input not better or worse than InputBox, just different, the end result is the same. With Input you get the "feeling" that your flow doesn't get interrupted, the downside is that you are not actually seeing what you type.